# How to exclude single-lettered title case words in a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have a database table that stores wishes from users. From that, I'd like to extract any title case words that they have submitted. I was able to obtain this output, however it includes single-lettered words such as **I** and **A**. Below is my current code, supposed we have a wish:

```
$x = "I wish for choice cards spelling PREJOIN 'coz I love Nature.";
preg_match_all('/\b([A-Z]+)\b/', $x, $matches);
array_shift($matches[0]);
foreach($matches[0] as $w) {
    $x = str_replace($w, "<b>$w</b>", $x);
}
echo $x;
```

The goal is to highlight the word **PREJOIN**, but with that code, it also highlights the word **I** where it shouldn't. Specifying the word is not possible as the wishes are being fetched from the database randomly, I just specified the value of `$x` as an example. How should the code be written with only highlighting the word PREJOIN?

***Current output:***
`I` wish for choice cards spelling `PREJOIN` 'coz `I` love Nature.

***Desired output:***
I wish for choice cards spelling `PREJOIN` 'coz I love Nature.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can achieve this without regex as well, https://3v4l.org/fiUoF

Comment: @user3783243 this works too, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take preg_replace() with the regular expression of Tim.

```
$x = "I wish for choice cards spelling PREJOIN 'coz I love Nature. A test with AB and XXX.";
$new = preg_replace('/\b[A-Z]{2,}\b/', '<b>$0</b>',$x);

echo $new;
```

Output:

I wish for choice cards spelling **PREJOIN** 'coz I love Nature. A test with **AB** and **XXX**.

Answer (score 3):

Well assuming the exclusion only applies to single capital letter words, you may match on `\b[A-Z]{2,}\b`:

```
preg_match_all('/\b([A-Z]{2,})\b/', $x, $matches);
```

However, if the intention is to exclude things like specific pronouns e.g. `I`, then you might do better to come up with a blacklist of single letter which should be excluded.

Full script:

```
$x = "I wish for choice cards spelling PREJOIN 'coz I love Nature.";
preg_match_all('/\b[A-Z]{2,}\b/', $x, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => PREJOIN
)
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your `preg_match` revision but it didn't highlight anything at all. Was it supposed not to highlight any word? Thank you!

Comment: @Aki Please try using the script which I added to the end of the answer.  I have confirmed that it is working.